# NullPointerException context static method

Tags: android, static, fragment, android-context

I have a class that uses static method from other class

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    // use static method to get text from file
    String articleString = FileRead.readRawTextFile();
    article.setText(articleString);
    ...
}
```

then I have class with the method

```
public class FileRead extends Application {

  private static Context ctx;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      ctx = this;
  }

  public static Context getContext(){
      return ctx;
  }

  public static String readRawTextFile()
  {
      InputStream inputStream = null;
      StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();     
      try {
          //****  E R R O R ***********************
          inputStream = FileRead.getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.plik);
          //***************************************
          InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
          BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
          String line;
          while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
              text.append(line);
              text.append('\n');
          }
          return text.toString();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("APP", "*** "+e, e);
          return null;
      }
  }
}
```

I get error NullPointerException. 
File is in res/raw. I think there is a problem with context but don't know why.

Comment: `FileRead.getContext()` returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

donfuxx is right; `FileRead.getContext()` is null.

However we can still get context! Pass it in as a parameter for `readRawTextFile()`.

So it becomes:

```
public static String readRawTextFile(Context context);
```

then change the `FileRead.getContext()` to

```
inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.plik);
```

then change your method call to this:

```
String articleString = FileRead.readRawTextFile(context);
```

replacing context with

- this or this.getContext() - if you are calling method within an activity
- getActivity() - if you calling this within a fragment (Beware: do a null check before using. getActivity() will return null if the fragment is not attached to an activity)
- _varWithContextIn - if you are calling this within say an setOnClickListener where "this" becomes the onClickListener you are creating.

Comment: Thanks for reply, at the beginning I tried to pass it, but I got the same error :(

Comment: I used example code from developer.android.com https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html they were getting text from string and I changed it to get text from file

Comment: Is it null pointer on the context line again? Maybe try changing the variable you pass into readRawTextFile from this to this.getContext() if that's allowed.

Comment: Yes the same line, can't use this.getContext()

Comment: Where are you calling the FileRead.readRawTextFile from? Are you in an activity or an onClickListener? What's it wrapped in? :)

Comment: class calling FileRead.readRawTextFile is not Activity - public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment

Comment: if you have a minute there is code developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html I only added FileRead class

Comment: Oh you're calling this from a Fragment!? Then you should try passing  getActivity() instead of this! BEWARE; getActivty() will be null if the fragment isn't attached to anything; a null check on getActivity() is ideal!. Doesn't like it? Try ((Context) getActivity())